# Same code one runs other not

Tags: c#

Struggling to find the reason why the same code behave differently. The answer provided does indeed run, but when I type the same code from the solution manual, I got an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`. I just cannot see where my problem lies.

Code from solution manual, class Date:

```
// Exercise 10.6 Solution: Date.cs
// Date class declaration.
using System;

public class Date
{
   private int month; // 1-12
   private int day; // 1-31 based on month
   private int year; // >0

   private static readonly int[] DAYSPERMONTH = 
      { 0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };

   // constructor: use property Month to confirm proper value for month; 
   // use property Day to confirm proper value for day
   public Date(int theDay, int theMonth, int theYear )
   {
      Month = theMonth; // validate month
      Year = theYear; // validate year
      Day = theDay; // validate day
      Console.WriteLine( "Date object constructor for date {0}", this );
   } // end Date constructor

   // property that gets and sets the year
   public int Year
   {
      get
      {
         return year;
      } // end get
      private set
      {
         year = CheckYear( value );
      } // end set
   } // end property year

   // property that gets and sets the month
   public int Month
   {
      get
      {
         return month;
      } // end get
      private set // make writing inaccessible outside the class
      {
         month = CheckMonth( value );
      } // end set
   } // end property Month

   // property that gets and sets the day
   public int Day
   {
      get
      {
         return day;
      } // end get
      private set // make writing inaccessible outside the class
      {
         day = CheckDay( value );
      } // end set
   } // end property Day 

   // increment the day and check if doing so will change the month
   public void NextDay()
   {
      if ( !endOfMonth() )
         ++Day;
      else 
      {  
         Day = 1;
         NextMonth();
      }
   } // end method NextDay

   // increment the month and check if doing so will change the year
   public void NextMonth()
   {
      if ( Month < 12 )
         ++Month;
      else
      {
         Month = 1; 
         ++Year;
      }
   } // end method NextMonth

   // return a string of the form month/day/year
   public override string ToString()
   {
      return string.Format($"{Day:D2}/{Month:D2}/{Year}");
   } // end method ToString

   // utility method to confirm proper year value
   private int CheckYear( int testYear )
   {
      if ( testYear > 0 ) // validate year
         return testYear;
      else // year is invalid
         throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(
            "year", testYear, "year must greater than 0" );
   } // end method CheckYear

   // utility method to confirm proper month value
   private int CheckMonth( int testMonth )
   {
      if ( testMonth > 0 && testMonth <= 12 ) // validate month
         return testMonth;
      else // month is invalid 
         throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(
            "month", testMonth, "month must be 1-12" );
   } // end method CheckMonth

   // utility method to confirm proper day value based on month and year
   private int CheckDay( int testDay )
   {
      // Check if day in range for month
      if ( testDay > 0 && testDay <= DAYSPERMONTH[ Month ] )
         return testDay;

      // Check for leap year
      if ( testDay == 29 && leapYear() )
         return testDay;

      throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(
         "day", testDay, "day out of range for current month/year" );
   } // end method CheckDay

   // check for end of month
   private bool endOfMonth()
   {
      if ( leapYear() && Month == 2 && Day == 29 )
         return true;
      else
         return Day == DAYSPERMONTH[ Month ];
   } // end method endOfMonth

   private bool leapYear()
   {
      return Month == 2 && ( Year % 400 == 0 ||
         ( Year % 4 == 0 && Year % 100 != 0 ) );
   } // end method leapYear
} // end class Date
```

Code from solution manual, class DateTest:

```
// Exercise 10.6 Solution: DateTest
// Application tests Date class with year validation,
// NextDay and NextMonth methods.
using System;

public class DateTest
{
   // method Main begins execution of C# application
   public static void Main( string[] args )
   {
      Console.WriteLine( "Checking increment" );
      Date testDate = new Date( 18, 9, 1980 );

      // test incrementing of day, month and year
      for ( int counter = 0; counter < 40; counter++ )
      {
         testDate.NextDay();

         Console.WriteLine( "Incremented Date: {0}",
            testDate.ToString() );
      }
        Console.Read();// end for
   } // end Main
} // end class DateTest
```

My own copied code from Solution manual, class Date:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using static System.Console;

namespace Ex_10._06
{
    public class Date
    {
        private int day;
        private int month;
        private int year;

        private static readonly int[] DAYSPERMONTH = { 0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };

    public Date(int theDay, int theMonth, int theYear)
    {
        Day = theDay;
        Month = theMonth;
        Year = theYear;
        WriteLine($"Date object constructor for date {this}");
    }

    public int Year
    {
        get
        {
            return year;
        }
        private set
        {
            year = CheckYear(value);
        }
    }

    public int Month
    {
        get
        {
            return month;
        }
        private set
        {
            month = CheckMonth(value);
        }
    }

    public int Day
    {
        get
        {
            return day;
        }
        private set
        {
            day = CheckDay(value);
        }
    }

    public void NextDay()
    {
        if (!endOfMonth())
            ++Day;
        else
        {
            Day = 1;
            NextMonth();
        }
    }

    public void NextMonth()
    {
        if (Month < 12)
            ++Month;
        else
        {
            Month = 1;
            ++Year;
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", Day, Month, Year);
    }

    private int CheckYear(int testYear)
    {
        if (testYear >= 0)
            return testYear;
        else
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Year", testYear, "Year must be equal or greater than 0");

    }

    private int CheckMonth(int testMonth)
    {
        if (testMonth > 0 && testMonth <= 12)
            return testMonth;
        else
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Month", testMonth, "Month must be 1-12");

    }

    private int CheckDay(int testDay)
    {
        if (testDay > 0 && testDay <= DAYSPERMONTH[Month])
            return testDay;

        if (testDay == 29 && leapYear())
            return testDay;

        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Day", testDay, "Day out of range for current month/year");
    }

    private bool endOfMonth()
    {
        if (leapYear() && Month == 2 && Day == 29)
            return true;
        else
            return Day == DAYSPERMONTH[Month];            
    }

    private bool leapYear()
    {
        return Month == 2 && (Year % 400 == 0 || (Year % 4 == 0 && Year % 100 != 0));
    }
}
```

}

My own code copied from solution manual, class DateTest:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using static System.Console;

namespace Ex_10._06
{
    public class DateTest
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WriteLine("Checking increment");
            Date d1 = new Date(18, 9, 1979);

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                d1.NextDay();
                WriteLine($"Incremented Date: {d1.ToString()}");
            }            

            Read();
        }
    }
}
```

True to be told, I am still learning. Maybe there is something I have overlooked, but I have even copied the style how to indent, still it produces an ArgumentOutOfRangeException, while the original code does run. Thanks in advance for your time.

See image call stack:
[Call Stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eSN5.png)

Comment: You need to show the stack trace for your exception.

Comment: _"I got an argumentoutofrangeexception. I just cannot see where my problem lies."_: Of course you can see it. Why don't you look at all the information the exception is providing you? If you run your project in Visual Studio, then Visual Studio even points you at the line that threw the exception.

Comment: So which line does the error occur on, and in which of the four near identical pieces of code you've provided?

Comment: Put debug point inside for loop and check. Its loot of code to look at

Comment: There a bug in the `endOfMonth()` function.  (Both your code and solution manual)  If it is February 28th, the function will return 'true' regardless of whether or not it is a leap year.

Comment: Thanks all for your time, I followed what Alfie said, and change the order of the properties in the constructor, and indeed it runs. I thought the order does not matter, but it does, apparently. So another valuable lesson learned. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

The error you are facing is because you switched the order in which properties are given their values in the constructor. When you declare a new date, you do CheckDay before anything else, which works out whether the day is valid in the given month, but it is done before the month is specified so that's your exception.

In the original code

```
Month = theMonth; // validate month
Year = theYear; // validate year
Day = theDay; // validate day
```

In the your code

```
Day = theDay;
Month = theMonth;
Year = theYear;
```

This causes an error because a month needs to be defined before the date, as it checks the array using the current month as an index.

Specifically, in CheckDay(), this code is run

```
if (testDay > 0 && testDay <= DAYSPERMONTH[Month])
    return testDay;
```

Which, when `Month = null` evaluates to this

```
if (testDay > 0 && testDay <= DAYSPERMONTH[null])
```